# How to Importrange + Count on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif

I'm trying to import data from another worksheet and count it simultaneously. It's only producing 1 for me, rather than 11 - which is what it should be.

I've tried the following:

```
=COUNT(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Shirts!F:F"))
```

Comment: please try to change count to be counta

Comment: count will work only for non string cells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to run your importrange formula and allow access to link your sheets:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Shirts!F1")
```

then try:

```
=COUNT(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Shirts!F:F"))
```

also make sure your set is numeric

Answer (score 1):

To count cell that not blank please use:

```
=COUNTA(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Shirts!F:F"))
```